# Formating a number with specific spacing

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-arrayformula, google-sheets-cell-format

I'm attempting to pull a particular option value from Yahoo! into Google Sheets. The base URL is: https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/GOOG190418C00800000

When breaking the formula up, I have to concatenate several fields into the last part of the URL. The breakdown is:

`https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/` + `SYMBOL` + `DATE` + `C/P` + `PRICE`

The `price` has to have 5 integers, followed by a decimal point, followed by 3 integers. If the price does not fill all characters, a zero has to be inserted.

For example: 125.00 has to be `00125.000` and 47.50 would be `00047.500`.

What I'm trying to figure out is how to take a price in the format of `xx.xx` or `xxx.xx` and add the correct amount of 0s to complete the link.

Please let me know if my explanation above doesn't make sense or I have to add more data. Cells, where data is being pulled from, are arbitrary.

Comment: pls share a copy of your sheet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What I'm trying to figure out is how to take a price in the format of
>   `xx.xx` or `xxx.xx` and add the correct amount of 0s to complete the link.

```
=TEXT(A1, "00000.000")
```

[image: 0]

---

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(LEN(A1:A), TEXT(A1:A, "00000.000"), ))
```

[image: 0]

---

```
=SUBSTITUTE(TEXT(G7, "00000.000"), ".", "")
```

[image]